# Size of a request header field exceeds server limit error for wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, caching

I am getting below error for my Wordpress website, when I trying reproducing using curl I was getting this error too,
Can anyone tell me what configuration I need to change to fix this error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at xyz-zzz.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PHP built-in function will give you all the headers came with request.

```
<?php

getallheaders(); // this function will return array

?>
```

Also, this article maybe help you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-any-request-header-in-php/

Thank you